# Datatables - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

i have been trying to figure this out for the past 3 hrs, i decided to move from manipulating the DOM and use serverside ajax instead since im working with 10,000+ rows.

i have managed to get the data in the table and all seems well except for the fact that i keep getting an alert "Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0" and i cant figure out why!!

i searched and searched but havent found anything that works.

Could anyone be of help??

PS: i tried using

```
"columns": [

            { "data": 'UserName' }

        ]
```

but that didnt help at all...

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    stateSave: false,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "include/ssp.php",
    searchHighlight: true,
    "pageLength": 25,
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], ["10 lignes", "25 lignes", "50 lignes", "100 lignes", "Tout"]],
    "scrollY": "70vh",
    "pagingType": "simple",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": true,
    "bSortClasses": false,
    dom: '<"row"<"col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"B><"col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"p>><"row"<"col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"<"fsearch">><"col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"f>>rti',
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
        };
        stockAll = api.column( 4 ).data().reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );
        $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(stockAll);
        cfAll = api.column( 8 ).data().reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );
        $( api.column( 8 ).footer() ).html(cfAll);
    },
    drawCallback: function(settings){
        var api = this.api();
        $('td:nth-child(9)', api.table().container()).each(function () {
           $(this).attr('title', api.cell($(this).parent('tr'), 9).data());
        });
        $('td:nth-child(9)', api.table().container()).tooltip({
           container: 'body'
        });
        $('td:nth-child(5)', api.table().container()).each(function () {
            var stock = parseFloat(api.cell($(this).parent('tr'), 4).data());
            var resa = parseFloat(api.cell($(this).parent('tr'), 10).data());
            var total = stock-resa;
            if(resa > 0){
                $(this).attr('title', 'Stock réel: '+total);
            }
        });
        $('td:nth-child(5)', api.table().container()).tooltip({
           container: 'body'
        });          
    },
    buttons: [
        {
        extend: 'collection',
            text: 'R&eacute;glage',
            className: "btn-primary",
            autoClose: true,
            buttons: [
                        {
                        extend: 'collection',
                            text: 'Param&egrave;tres',
                            buttons: [
                                {
                                extend: 'pageLength',
                                    text: 'Ligne par page'
                                },
                                {
                                text: 'Cadre d&rsquo;image',
                                action: function displayImageFrame() {
                                        var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
                                        $("#right").toggle();
                                        $("#left").toggleClass("col-lg-7 col-lg-12");
                                        $("#left").toggleClass("col-md-7 col-md-12");
                                        table.draw();
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                extend: 'collection',
                                    text: 'Colonnes',
                                    buttons: [
                                                {
                                                extend: 'colvis',
                                                    columns: [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    extend: 'colvisGroup',
                                                    text: 'Groupe - Prix',
                                                    show: [ 0,1,2,5,6,7,11 ],
                                                    hide: [ 3,4,8,9,10 ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    extend: 'colvisGroup',
                                                    text: 'Groupe - Stock',
                                                    show: [ 0,1,2,4,8,9,10 ],
                                                    hide: [ 3,5,6,7,11 ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                extend: 'colvisRestore', 
                                                    text: 'Colonnes par d&eacute;faut'
                                                },
                                            ]
                                },
                                {
                                text: 'Plein &eacute;cran',
                                action: function toggleFullScreen() {
                                          if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
                                              !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement ) {  // current working methods
                                            if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
                                              document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
                                            } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
                                              document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
                                            } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                                              document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
                                            } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                                              document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
                                            }
                                          } else {
                                            if (document.exitFullscreen) {
                                              document.exitFullscreen();
                                            } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
                                              document.msExitFullscreen();
                                            } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                                              document.mozCancelFullScreen();
                                            } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
                                              document.webkitExitFullscreen();
                                            }
                                          }
                                        }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                        extend: 'collection',
                            text: '(D&eacute;)S&eacute;lectionner',
                            buttons: [
                                {
                                extend: 'selectAll',
                                    text: 'S&eacute;lectionner tout'
                                },
                                {
                                text: 'S&eacute;lectionner filtr&eacute;',
                                action: function SelectFiltered(e) {
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        var table = $("#myTable").DataTable();
                                        table.rows({filter:"applied"}).select();
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                extend: 'selectNone',
                                    text: 'Tout d&eacute;selectionner'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                        extend: 'collection',
                            text: 'Export',
                            buttons: [
                                {
                                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                                text: 'Copier tout',
                                exportOptions: {
                                    columns: [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                                text: 'Copier s&eacute;lection',
                                exportOptions: {
                                    columns: [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
                                    modifier: {
                                        selected: true
                                    }
                                }
                                },
                                {
                                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                                text: 'CSV s&eacute;lection',
                                title: 'Order',
                                filename: 'Order',
                                fieldSeparator: ';',
                                extension: '.csv',
                                exportOptions: {
                                    columns: [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
                                    modifier: {
                                        selected: true
                                    }
                                }
                                },
                                {
                                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                                text: 'Excel s&eacute;lection',
                                title: 'Order',
                                exportOptions: {
                                    columns: [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
                                    modifier: {
                                        selected: true
                                    }
                                }
                                },
                                {
                                    extend: 'print',
                                    text: 'Imprimer tout',
                                    exportOptions: {
                                            columns: ':visible'
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    extend: 'print',
                                    text: 'Imprimer s&eacute;lection',
                                    exportOptions: {
                                        columns: [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
                                        modifier: {
                                            selected: true
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                                    text: 'PDF',
                                    title: 'Order',
                                    exportOptions: {
                                           columns: ':visible'
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                                text: 'Enregistrer la s&eacute;lection',
                                title: 'Selection',
                                exportOptions: {
                                    columns: [2],
                                    modifier: {
                                        selected: true
                                    }
                                }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        {
        "className": 'control',
        "orderable": false,
        "targets":   0
        },
        {
        "orderable": false,
        "className": 'select-checkbox',
        "targets":   1
        },
        {
        "data": 'product_reference',
        "targets" : 2
        },
        {
        "data": 'product_brand',
        "targets" : 3
        },
        {
        "data": 'stock_qty',
        "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
            if ( cellData < 1 ) {
                $(td).css("background-color", "#FF6961");
              }
            },
        "targets" : 4
        },
        {
        "defaultContent": "-",
        "targets": 5
        },
        {
        "data": 'product_tb1',"createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
            if ( (cellData == 0) || (cellData == "#N/A") || (cellData == 999)) {
                $(td).css("background-color", "#FDFD96");
              }
            },
        "targets": 6
        },
        {
        "data": 'product_rrp',
        "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
            if ( (cellData < 1) || (cellData == "#N/A") ) {
                $(td).css("background-color", "#FDFD96");
              }
            },
        "targets": 7
        },
        {
        "data": 'product_cf',
        "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
            if ( cellData > 1 ) {
                $(td).css("background-color", "#BDECB6");
              }
            },
        "targets": 8
        },
        {
        "data": 'product_cf_date',
        "targets": 9
        },
        {
        "defaultContent": "-",
        "targets": 10
        },
        {
        "data": 'product_pmp',
        "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
            if ( (cellData < 1) || (cellData == "#N/A") ) {
                $(td).css("background-color", "#FDFD96");
              }
            },
        "targets": 11
        },
        {
        "visible": false,
        "targets": [9,10,11]
        }
        ],
    "order": [[ 2, 'asc' ]],
    select: {
        style: 'multi+shift',
        selector: 'tr>td:nth-child(2)'
    },
    "language": {
        "sProcessing":     "Traitement en cours...",
        "sSearch":         "",//"Rechercher&nbsp;:",
        "sLengthMenu":     "Afficher _MENU_ lignes",
        "sInfo":           "_START_ &agrave; _END_ sur _TOTAL_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
        "sInfoEmpty":      "Affichage de l'&eacute;l&eacute;ment 0 &agrave; 0 sur 0 &eacute;l&eacute;ment",
        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtr&eacute; de _MAX_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments au total)",
        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Chargement en cours...",
        "sZeroRecords":    "Aucun &eacute;l&eacute;ment &agrave; afficher",
        "sEmptyTable":     "Aucune donn&eacute;e disponible dans le tableau",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":      "Premier",
            "sPrevious":   "Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent",
            "sNext":       "Suivant",
            "sLast":       "Dernier"
        },
        "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending":  ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant",
            "sSortDescending": ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre d&eacute;croissant"
        },
        buttons: {
            colvis: "Colonnes visibles",
            selectAll: "S&eacute;lectionner tout",
            selectNone: "Tout d&eacute;selectionner"
        },
        select: {
            rows: {
                _: " (%d lignes s&eacute;lectionn&eacute;)",
                //0: " (Cliquez sur une ligne pour la s&eacute;lectionner)",
                0: "",
                1: " (1 ligne s&eacute;lectionn&eacute;)"
            }
        }
},
colReorder: true,
keys: {
    columns: ':nth-child(3)',
    focus: ':eq(2)',
    blurable: true
},
responsive: true,
initComplete: function () {
    this.api().columns(3).every( function () {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select id="filter_brand" class="form-control input-sm"><option value="">------</option></select>')
            .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
            .on( 'change', function () {
                $(this).blur();
                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                    $(this).val()
                );

                column
                    .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                    .draw();
            } );

        column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
        } );
    } );
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a comma here:

```
"visible": false,
"targets": [9,10,11]
```

Here:

```
},
```

Then carry on

```
],
"order": [[ 2, 'asc' ]],
select: {
  style: 'multi+shift',
```

This caught me out once in a similar way I am sure.

Comment: Did this help at all?